# Pointers to Beginners (Robotics as Hobby)

Tags: robotics, wifi

I am interested in taking up robotics as a hobby. I am somewhat familiar with programming (not very advanced) and would like to get some pointers to recommended books / robotic kits that will help me get started. Something that is not too esoteric. I can hopefully get to that level later!

Specifically I am more interested in using WiFi for communications (as opposed to Bluetooth).

I did purchase Lego Mindstorm recently....but looking for additional resources.

Thanks!

Comment: the reason you see bluetooth so often because it is significantly more cost effective. If you need wifi that is understandable, but just letting you know your cost is going up.

Comment: This question is very old and does not fit the format of the site, which is to avoid asking for opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't go wrong by reading [Making Things Move](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071741674) and [Making Things Talk](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596510519)

Answer (score 0):

I am a CTO of a Robotics company, and I have been lucky enough to see many students who have good interests in Robotics.

My suggestion is to start with an Arduino which is cheap and easy, yet powerful to learn electronics and software.